# ¿Cuáles son los límites en el uso del sufijo "-ero"?

Tags: sufijos

Si a alguien le encanta el café, se le puede decir "cafetero."  ¿Hasta dónde este mecanismo se puede extender?  Yo pienso que se puede decir "Soy muy juguero" (me encanta tomar el jugo), "Mi hermano es súper telefonero" (a mi hermano le encanta usar el teléfono a cada rato), etc.  Alguien me comentó aquí que "cafetero" sí, "juguero" y "telefonero", etc., no.

¿Estoy en lo cierto, y se pueden construir este tipo de palabras de manera general?  Si no, ¿cuándo sí y cuándo no?

Comment: Sin embargo, pese a lo que enlaza @murderofcrows, hay muchas palabras en las que este sufijo indica afición a algo, incluso recogidas en el DLE: cafetero, niñero, futbolero...

Answer (score 4):

No creo que puedan construirse palabras con *-ero* en este sentido de manera general porque el uso parece bastante limitado, pero eso es una cuestión del tipo de "qué vino primero, el huevo o la gallina": si no es natural usar *-ero* de esta forma, es porque no se usa así en muchas palabras, pero no se usa en muchas palabras porque no suena natural.

Algunas de las palabras a las que se añade este *-ero* designan aficiones socialmente bien reconocidas: el fútbol, el café, la cerveza. El caso de *juguero*, que OP menciona, no es muy reconocido, pero por mi parte lo encuentro totalmente natural; no así *telefonero*, donde la relación entre la palabra y el significado, si uno no la escuchó antes, es un poco más difícil de hacer.

Hablando de aficiones, en Argentina se le dice también *motoquero* (no **motero*) al miembro de la subcultura de las motocicletas (= inglés *biker*). Pero por otro lado *bicicletero* es una persona que repara bicicletas o una estructura de metal para atarlas.

Otras de estas palabras en *-ero* no se refieren a aficiones sino a rasgos o tendencias de carácter: en mi dialecto se dice *liero* a una persona que tiende a complicar las cosas o a causar problemas (hacer lío o líos), *teatrero* al histriónico, al que sobreactúa o hace un drama de situaciones que no lo ameritan; la generación de mis padres dice *espamentero* al que gusta de hacer *espamento* (= [aspaviento](http://dle.rae.es/?id=43PdSYt)). De las acepciones de *[agorero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=16miGim)* no me consta que se use habitualmente ninguna salvo la primera, que también es un rasgo de carácter: el pesimista que siempre está prediciendo desgracias. Me da la impresión de que esta forma de usar *-ero* es un poco más productiva que la que se refiere a aficiones, pero la verdad es que semánticamente están muy cerca una de otra.

En fin, creo que el uso de *-ero* para indicar rasgos de carácter puede extenderse hasta cierto punto para indicar aficiones, pero no cualquiera, sino alguna afición (o actividad, o subcultura) que esté bien reconocida y delimitada socialmente o quizá ritualizada, como tomar café o cerveza, o el fútbol u otro deporte masivo.

Comment: Creo que la forma más genérica de entender el sufijo *-ero* es para decir *el que tiene oficio relacionado con [sustantivo base]". De ahí, cafetero (que trabaja/hacer café) o cocinero (que se encarga de la cocina), bicicletero (que trabaja con o arregla bicis).  De oficio a afición hay nada más un salto muy pequeño.